# How to add corners to horizontal tab bar in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How can I add round corners to the horizotal tabs in jQuery Mobile 1.4?
Despite the ui-corner-all class is already present and the UL element has set border radius, the corners are still without the radius. On vertical list the radius works, but not here.

You can test it directly on the [official page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/tabs/#Usenavbarfortabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***CSS***

```
.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-tabs-anchor{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gnhebr0g/1/)

> If you just want the first and last to be rounded

```
li:first-of-type .ui-link.ui-btn.ui-tabs-anchor{
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px
}

li:last-of-type .ui-link.ui-btn.ui-tabs-anchor{
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gnhebr0g/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.ui-navbar li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.ui-navbar li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this should do the trick

```
.tab_item {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```